# Using diff-in-diff and fixed effects in Stata

Tags: stata, difference-in-difference

I am doing research using Stata on state-level contraception policy effects on male labour outcomes (e.g. wages). I am utilizing the laws between 1960 and 1976 when Roe vs. Wade was not ruling and the states themselves could have their own laws. The treatment here would be to live in a state where women had access to contraception technologies.

I have defined a man as treated in four different ways. First, I create a dataset where I plug in the year for which 16 year old women having access to birth control pills by law in that state (c16) and also 18 year old women having access to birth control pills (c18) by law (abortion rights are coded the same way (a16 and a18)). If the state did restrict all of this, the value would be 0. So if a man turned 16 after the state enforced a law stating that abortion was allowed for 16-year olds, he would be considered as treated in the c16-variable and vice versa. Further, I merge this dataset with my IPUMS data which contains census-samples from 1970, 1980, 1990 and 2000 of men born between 1934 and 1982.

Now to my concerns: I would think I need to use fixed effects and `xtreg` but I am not sure how?

Comment: This is poised awkwardly between a request for Stata-specific advice, which could be off-topic here, and a request for statistical advice. If it's really a statistical question, you need not mention Stata or details like `xtreg`. If your question mixes both elements, you would be better off on Statalist. (No one familiar with the latter could accuse me of hostility to Stata.)